# GetValue() from Google AppScript can't get mail with subdomain (something@mydomain.com.mx)

Tags: google-apps-script

When I use this code:

```
var correoEncargado = ssAltaResponsables.getRange(j,4).getDisplayValue();
```

The content of the cell in the Google sheet is "something@mydomain.com.mx"
And when I look inside the var I have "something@mydomain.(class)"

So it's an invalid mail and I can't use it forward.

When the content of the cell is something like "somethin@mydomain.com", it works fine. It only fails when there is a subdomain in the mail.

I have tried with all kind of mail and it only fails with @something.com.mx

```
var correoEncargado = ssAltaResponsables.getRange(3,4).getDisplayValue();
```

The cell is: something@mydomain.com.mx

I expect: something@mydomain.com.mx

And I get: something@mydomain.(class)

Comment: I have also tried with getValue instead of getDisplayValue with the same (negative) result.

Comment: Can you send a email manually to that domain? It only looks like `something@mydomain.(class)`, but the actual email is the same. Try `console.log(email)`

Comment: For now I solved it putting the mail in UPPERCASE and it works.

Comment: I just tried this `function getAnEmail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var val=sh.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  Logger.log(val);//log is something@mydomain.com.mx
}` and it's works just fine.

Comment: How are you evaluating the value returned by ` ssAltaResponsables.getRange(j,4).getDisplayValue();`?

Comment: The email direction is correct. I can send mail without problem to the email.  The problem is only when i put ".com" (midominio.com.mx) if I put .edu instead of .com it work (midominio.edu.mx). In uppercase it works fine with JHON@MYDOMAIN.COM.MX (for soon I solved it with this trick).

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing bug that has been reported here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114358543

To clarify though -

- Logger.log provides the right output now (something@mydomain.com.mx)
- Console.log provides the right output (something@mydomain.com.mx)
- `getDisplayValue()` & `getValue()` too gives out the right output (something@mydomain.com.mx)
- Debug still shows it as "something@mydomain.(class)"